# SpriteKit: Add SKSpriteView To The View

Tags: swift, sprite-kit, screen, skspritenode, metal

I have an image for the background, which I am trying to assign to the screen

My code:

```
let image = SKSpriteNode(imageNamed: "background")
func addBackground(sizeNode: CGFloat){
    image.size = CGSizeMake(sizeNode, sizeNode)
    image.position.x = xPos
    image.position.y = yPos
    GameScene().addChild(image)
}
```

The Programm compiles with no error messages, but on my screen is no visible node (node counter = 1 should be 41) and I got following line in the console:

> '<'CAMetalLayer: 0x13cd07c10>: calling -display has no effect.

Hopefully you can help me out!

Comment: Try `self.addChild(image)`

Comment: If I do this I get an error in the AppDelegate in the line: `class AppDelegate: UIResponder, UIApplicationDelegate{`and it says: <Thread 1: signal SIGABRT> with an uncaught exception of type NSException.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your last line creates a new instance of a GameScene and adds the image to it. This instance is not assigned to a variable and never added to the screen.

```
 GameScene().addChild(image)
```

Check if you have already created a screen and presented it in an skview. Add your background to this scene